# Generate iterator from complex python array

Tags: python, generator

Given an list like [(1, 2), (1, 2)] in python. How to create a generator which generate a list [1, 1].

Comment: what dou mean by a list _[1,1]_ ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains.

Comment: That's not an array, that's a list of tuples.

Comment: the first element of tuple inner. @scharette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that yields the first element of each item in an input list.

```
def yield_first(x):
    for item in x:
        yield item[0]

list(yield_first([(1, 2), (1, 2)]))
# returns
[1, 1]
```